# Storing critical data into MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, security

This is not a programming question at all. Let me explain: I am creating a game, for which I need a Database that will store users registration data (e.g. username, email, password). If a user wins, he/she will earn Cash Points. The user will be able to exchange his/her Cash Points by real money, so I consider that the Cash Points is a very, very critical data. My question is: would you store the Cash Points data in the same "users" table? Or would you create a new table named "cash" (for instance) and then store it into? (from a security point of view)

Thanks

Comment: You should store only a hash of users' passwords. Never the actual password.

Comment: And by "hash" it's implied that you're using a password-specific hashing method like [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best if you implement a simple ledger system whereby transactions are recorded against the user's account as credit or debits, and the account itself has a total that can be audited.

You **must** keep a record of transactions performed if you're involving cash or cash-like currency. If someone complains about missing money you need to be able to verify every transaction that affected their balance and uncover any discrepancies.

This also presumes you're making use of transactions to avoid committing incomplete transactions. The balance adjustment and transaction record should be part of the same transaction.

As always, **test** this as ruthlessly as you can.

Comment: All answers are great but I chose this one because it made me think... how am I supposed to implement such a complex transaction system? Can you recommend me any lecture on this subject? Could you tell me how can I keep a record of transactions performed? Does PayPal help me with that task? Cheers!

Comment: You'll want to record things like `(tx_id, account_id, amount)` where `tx_id` is a transaction identifier, `account_id` represents the account in question, and `amount` is a positive or negative number. That way the account "balance" should be `SELECT SUM(amount) FROM account_transactions WHERE account_id=?` but for performance reasons this could be saved into an `accounts.balance` column. Usually debits to one account are credits from another, and vice-versa, so if you issue in-game currency, you'll debit an account where these "come from" to allow auditing.

Comment: Under some schools of thinking, `SUM(amount)` should always equal zero. That is all credits and debits cancel each-other out. This way money never magically appears anywhere, you're just moving it around. It also makes it friendly for your accountant.

Answer (score 1):

It is considered bad design if you store cash points in the users table. Tables should be `normalized`. You should store cash points in a separate table and use the `userId` as the foreign key in that table. You could look into encrypting Cash Points table data as well.

Answer (score 1):

Cashpoints definitely in a separate table but not from security perspective. It's better from design perspective and will allow you to keep a log of CashPoint changes for each user.

Answer (score 1):

Well you should create a database design that resembles a **bank balance**. That way you can keep track of all changes, this is

```
create table balance
(id int,
debit numeric (10,2),
credit numeric (10,2),
balance_before numeric(10,2),
balance_after numeric(10,2),
timestamp datetime,
user_id int,
description varchar(32),
...
);
```